# REGEXP_LIKE exclude strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How can I exclude next below strings using REGEXP_LIKE.

When the next character of 'TEST' string is **-** or **.** or **@**

Examples:

```
   TEST@TEST.COM
   XX@TEST-XX.COM
   TEST.TEST@LION.NL
   TEST@DSFFDS.BE
   NO.EMAIL@TEST.COM
```

But include:

```
TESTTOM@LION.BE
HI@TESTP.COM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
...
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(field,'TEST[-.@]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
WITH t AS (
           SELECT 'TEST@TEST.COM' COL1
             FROM dual
            UNION   
           SELECT 'XX@TEST-XX.COM'
             FROM dual
            UNION  
           SELECT 'TEST.TEST@LION.NL'
             FROM dual
            UNION  
           SELECT 'TEST@DSFFDS.BE'
             FROM dual
            UNION  
           SELECT 'NO.EMAIL@TEST.COM'
             FROM dual
          )     
SELECT t.col1
  FROM t
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COL1,'TEST[-.@]')
;
```

Comment: You should remove the `^` to match `NO.EMAIL@TEST.COM`